# To remove clouds of Landsat 8 surface reflectance products

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloud-gis, median

I want to remove clouds from the collection of images and replace new values with pixels of clouds. I have written code, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/nadiajabeen/chitral");

//---------Image Collection Landsat8---------------
var image=ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterDate('2020-08-01','2020-08-17')
.filterBounds(table)
.sort('CLOUD_COVER', false);
Map.setCenter(72.04589459686508,36.6838680049941,7)
print(image)
var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
};
// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 3,3, 'Cloud_shadows').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 5,5, 'Cloud').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
  var c = clouds(image);
  image = image.updateMask(cs);
  return image.updateMask(c);
};
var mosaicfree = maskClouds(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and change this:

```
pixel_qa >> 
QA_PIXEL

return getQABits(QA, 3,3, 'Cloud_shadows').eq(0); >>
return getQABits(QA, 3,4, 'Cloud_shadows').eq(0);

return getQABits(QA, 5,5, 'Cloud').eq(0); >>
return getQABits(QA, 10,11, 'Cloud').eq(1);
```